# Prevent a material from darkening in Render view

Tags: texturing, materials, lighting

Using the EEVEE engine. In my model I have a texture to represent a Ceiling light. [[image: The texture1]

The top light is darker than the image is. In Dev Look it matches but not in Render Mode. I can't find anything in the Material tab that makes it match either. Is there a way to make this image as bright as the source texture without having to flash a light source onto it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside the shader editor for the image, replace the Principled shader with an emission shader. Your image looks dark because of the shadows on it, and giving it an Emission shader will remove the shadows.

Comment: Which nodes do I connect? I have the emission between the texture and  Material Output.

Comment: connect the texture's `Color` output to emission's `Color` input. Connect emission output to material output.

Comment: @GoldenGemGames You could also have left the Principled BSDF, it has an Emission input where you could have connected the texture's color output to. This is sometimes more helpful / better instead of using just an Emission shader when you want an object to have a material showing when the light is "switched off", i.e. the Emission Strength value is set to 0.